# Вопрос по CMS iPHPortal

Tags: cms

доброго всем.
Кто-нибудь работает(ал) с CMS **iPHPortal**?
Вроде должен быть каталог с php-шкой по адресу:

```
http://[site-name.xx]/shop/catalog/
```

там теперь три каталога:
about
discont
prices
 + два файла 145.php и index.php
Я просто такую экзотическую CMS не разу не видел, что странно, в бэкапах тоже такого каталога не увидел, которые делал за день.
Теперь заявили, что сайт не работает.
Хотелось бы услышать администрировавших когда-либо данную CMS.
Возможно так и должна выглядеть структура каталога?
А если нет, то попрошу (сильно-сильно) скинуть содержимое каталога **catalog** если он есть, там по идеи, должен лежать всего-лишь один файл **index.php**.
P.S. База данных там вообще на хостинге не засвечивается (как так?)

Comment: Не беритесь за администратирование индуский кмс, посмотрите в файлах куда уходят данные (должен быть файлл с логином и паролем для записи в бд). 

Так же могу посоветовать не исключать возможность того, что бд нету. И вся инфа складируется в файлах. Найти нужные поможет поиск с ключем например одного из товаров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не мучайте себя этим хламом.
[image]

Comment: в значении local Value эти параметры **ON** в значении Master Value - ***OFF**
Это может быть причиной?

Comment: Не знаю, но лучше не пользуйтесь этой системой. register_globals всегда должна быть off, ведь это страшное нарушение безопасности!